# Why such a large difference between Odds Ratios and Hazard Ratios?

Tags: cox-model, proportional-hazards

I am studying the risk of dementia secondary to hearing loss. I have fashioned a Cox time-dependent model with multiple covariates, all with factor levels, but have also done a logistic model for individual covariates as well. The logistic univariate model shows a sequential increase in odds ratio for increased hearing loss (more hearing loss leads to increased risk of dementia):

| HEARING | OR | 2.50% | 97.50% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| minimal | 2.54 | 2.42 | 2.66 |
| minimal-moderate | 3.78 | 3.63 | 3.95 |
| severe | 5.28 | 5.08 | 5.50 |
| profound | 7.52 | 7.23 | 7.83 |

When I do the Cox time-dependent model, I lose the sequential increase in risk hazard:

| HEARING | exp(coef) | lower .95 | upper .95 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| minimal | 4.15 | 3.98 | 4.33 |
| minimal-moderate | 4.03 | 3.91 | 4.16 |
| severe | 3.69 | 3.5 | 3.79 |
| profound | 3.63 | 3.52 | 3.73 |

This is a huge dataset with large numbers in each category (tens of thousands). and everything is significant at a p < -10^22.

Is the difference that the Cox time-dependent model already includes the timing of the covariate? How is this possible? It has been shown that worse hearing leads to increased risk of dementia, so this part is not new in the literature. I have only one value for each subject's hearing, but at different ages of their lives.
Thanks for any insight someone might have.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It would help if you could provide more details about both the logistic regression and the Cox model. In particular, if you "have only one value for each subject's hearing, but at different ages of their lives,"  how was that information entered into the Cox time-dependent model? What other types of time-varying predictors were included? How was the date of dementia evaluated for the Cox model? The logistic model just evaluates yes/no for the event, so how did you account for the incomplete follow-up/censoring that might lead to bias?

Comment: I used R and its tmerge function to place the time of hearing loss at the subject's age for the Cox model. It was entered as a covariate with the factor of severity and the age of diagnosis. Dementia was the event, 1/0 based on diagnosis and year of diagnosis. Death was a censoring event.

Comment: I have also assessed the significance of the difference between the factors in the Cox model as well as the logistic model. In the Cox model, there is, for instance, no difference between minimal and minimal-moderate levels (p-value = .25), or between severe and profound (p-value 0.31). On the other hand, in the logistic model, the differences in ranks are highly significant at all levels. Does the Cox time-dependent model just remove the effects of age in some fashion? So that it's not the severity of the hearing loss, but the hearing loss itself that matters?

Comment: To be sure, I'd want to look at the data and run things (and I'm retired, so, I'm not sure I'd do that) but my guess is in the nature of the methods.  And my interpretation would be that the severity of hearing loss does not affect the timing of dementia, but does affect the severity.